# Error while installing hangfire with NuGet

Tags: nuget, hangfire

I'm getting the below error when I try to install Hangfire on my project in Visual Studio 2010

External packages cannot depend on packages that target projects

[image]

I tried installing Newtonsoft.Json seperately to see that that resolved it, but it didn't help.

Comment: Check you have the latest version of NuGet installed. Also another problem, which is not the cause of the error you are seeing, is that Hangfire.Core only has assemblies for .NET 4.5 which I do not believe are supported by Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of HangFire depends on .NET 4.5+, which 2010 can't target.

If you use the older versions of Owin & HangFire, things work

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb -Version 2.1.0
Install-Package HangFire -Version 0.9.1
```

Anyhow, worked for me with the SQL Server provider & IIS.